# What do I need to change for my code to move from Jstree 1.0-rc3 to Jstree 3.3.5

Tags: javascript, jstree

I need to add some new jstree functionality to my website and I discovered I was using a very old version so I replaced jstree.js with latest version and now an existing page that uses jstree is not being rendered as a jstree

This is the jstree javascript on my webpage, can anyone help me see why this wouldn't work with latest version of jstree. (I haven't changed JQuery, still using 1.92)

I must confess I cannot remember how this works.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" class="source below">
    $(function () {
      $("#songchanges").jstree({
          "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","cookie"],
          "core" : { "initially_open" : [ "phtml_1" ] }
      })
      .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
      })
      .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
          var href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
          if(href!="#"){
              top.frames["main"].location = href; }
          else {
              $(this).jstree('toggle_node', data.rslt.obj[0]);
          }
        })
      ;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Think I have fixed this and  the problem was i was using an old version of jstree theme that didnt work with latest jstree.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I updated code to use latest version of jstree.ks but was still using an old version of jstree theme that did not work with latest jstree.js